# Join nested query NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

How do you do this query in NHibernate, with criteria or `QueryOver`?

```
select r.relationshipidentifier, r.publicrelationshipid
from relationship r 
inner join (
    select max(asofdate) as asofdate, s.relationshipidentifier
    from relationship s
    group by s.relationshipidentifier
) m
on r.asofdate = m.asofdate and r.relationshipidentifier = m.relationshipidentifier
```

Assume

```
public class Relationship {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime AsOfDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid RelationshipIdentifier { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid PublicRelationshpId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the inner join can be described by a subquery.
something to the effect of -

```
QueryOver.Of<Relationship>()
.SelectList(list =>
    list.SelectMax(r => r.AsOfDate),
    list.GroupProperty(r=> r.RelationshipIdentifier)
)
```

and you can use the `WithSubquery` method of QueryOver to inner join to that subquery.
see [this article](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx) for further details on QueryOver API.

Comment: But how can you do a join using WithSubquery?

Comment: Couldn't find any way to join using WithSubquery